# Include only var from one php file to another

Tags: php, html

I have one variable in `url.php`.
I want to access it in multiple other files. I tried to include `url.php` in all those files. But there is one issue.

```
<?php
 include 'url.php';   //include url.php
 echo "My id is : $myid";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- AddThis Smart Layers END -->
</head>
//somecontent
<body>
```

`url.php` has html code including buttons, div etc. All of them get included when I include `url.php`.

How can I include only php variable and skip other html code from url.php.

url.php looks like this:

```
<?php
$myid=$_POST['myid'];
echo "myID is : <br>";
echo $myid;
?>
<html>
   <head>
    <html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
     </head>
  //some othe html stuff
</html>
```

Comment: @subzero: I could not remove it. It contains UI of my site!

Comment: I really like the magic of commenting: `include 'url.php';   //include url.php`

Answer (score 1):

```
You can put some condition there like isset().
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['myid']))
  {
   $myid=$_POST['myid'];
   echo "myID is : <br>";
   echo $myid;
  }
 else{
?>
 <html>
  <head>
   <html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
  </head>
    //some othe html stuff
 </html>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: even after this if I include above code, it will include html.

Comment: if $_POST['myid'] variable is not set then it will include html. u can modify include condition. Are you getting $_POST['myid'] variable in every page?

Answer (score 1):

The Other solution is you can save the variable in session and later you can retrieve the value in other pages also.

url.php

```
<?php
$myid=$_POST['myid'];
session_start();
$_SESSION['my_id']=$myid;
?>
```

You can use the variable like this.
useMyId.php``

```
<?
session_start();
$var=$_SESSION['my_id'];

echo "Here is the variable".$var;
?>
```

Comment: Intelligent answer. But on my page there is one already ongoing session which start with `session_start();`. Any posibilities for collision ? anything like session1 and session2 to start seperately?

Comment: If session already start on the page then no need to add session_start(); But make sure that the session must start before assignment of $_SESSION['my_id']=$myid; and $var=$_SESSION['my_id'];

Comment: situation is little complex. The page which will have above content is loaded by ajax request into index.php. Index.php have some code which uses session_start() to start facebook login status.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this. The only way is to remove the HTML and include that somewhere else. A call to include is opening the file then running `eval` on the content. If it contains vital UI parts of your site you should reconsider your design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

you could declare a variable in every php file before including the `url.php`.
like this:
  `$uservar = 1;`

then in your url.php put the html block in an if statement

`if($usevar != 1){`
  `HTML-BlOCK`
  `}`